# How to make workable given 'All' as value of state to render all Products

Tags: reactjs

I can't take All products from button 'All' already given as value of state, fetching other categories from DummyJson => All as all products from API taken products and other buttons(categories) for that products?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NavBar from "../NavBar";
import "./Categories.css";
function Categories({ prepareData, handleFilter }) {
  const [categories, setCategoires] = useState(["All"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products/categories/`)
      .then((req) => req.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setCategoires([...categories, ...res]);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div className="categoriesContainer">
        {categories.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="singleCategoryContainer"
              onClick={() =>
                categories === "All" ? prepareData : handleFilter(item)
              }
            >
              {item}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Categories;


import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Categories from "../components/Categories/Categories";
import SingleProduct from "./SingleProduct";
import "./Products.css";

function Products() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=100")
      .then((req) => req.json())
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.products));
  }, []);

  const handleFilter = (data) => {
    setFilter(data);
  };

  const prepareData = () => {
    if (filter === "all") {
      return setFilter(products);
    }
    return products.filter((item) => item.category === filter);
  };

  if (products.length === 0) {
    return <div className="loader">Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Categories prepareData={prepareData} handleFilter={handleFilter} />
      <div className="productsContainer">
        {prepareData().map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="singleProductContainer">
              <SingleProduct data={item} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

i try to send as prop, function where i am filtering if is "all" to render all the products otherwise filtered products for specific category to give me when i click on some of the button for categories

Comment: You've lost `()` - `categories === "All" ? prepareData() : handleFilter(item)`

Comment: How you mean that i lost? parenthesses?

Comment: You never call `prepareData`

Comment: i tried also that way, still not working, i will check again, thanks by the way :)